# which leads the other $v_{1}=cos(wt)\;\;\; , \; \; v_{2}=cos(wt-\pi)$?

Tags: calculus

$v_{1}=cos(wt)\;\;\; , \; \; v_{2}=cos(wt-\pi)$
Does $v_{1}$ lead $v_{2}$ or $v_{2}$ leads $v_{1}$
I'm very confused even after plotting both functions :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean leads?

Comment: Phase difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phase always indicates the angular displacement of the motion from the origin.so v2 as mentioned is delayed by a phase of 180 degrees from origin.so v2 is lagging behind v1..if it was cos(wt+180°) it will lead.

Comment: what if it was :   
$v_{1}=cos(wt-0.4\pi)\;,\;v_{2}=cos(wt+0.8\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

There really are a few different ways to interpret this based on the context it is used in.

In a *way*, you can think of $v_2$ as $v_1$ translated forwards by $\pi$. So $v_2$ is leading $v_1$. But obviously in a larger sense, you can't really tell what is leading what...

And of course, it can be interpreted another way round too.

Comment: what if it was :   
$v_{1}=cos(wt-0.4\pi)\;,\;v_{2}=cos(wt+0.8\pi)$

Comment: @SmartCoder then $v_1$ leads $v_2$ since the former is translated forwards while the latter is translated backwards, relative to $\cos(\omega t)$.

Comment: I think v2 leads v1 . Read the answer above

Comment: @SmartCoder It's just a different way of interpretation. The accepted answer's way is to consider the phase at the point of observation. My way is to consider $t<0$ as the event yet to happen.